# Why my json code is not working in ASP.NET Core using VS 2022?

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get fields from my database into a list and pass them as data to JSON code in my index file.

Home controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ExpenseTrackerApplication2023;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using ExpenseTracker.Data;

namespace ExpenseTracker.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext Context { get; }
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signManager;
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signManager, ApplicationDbContext _context)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signManager = signManager;
            this.Context = _context;
        }

        [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize(Roles =("Admin"))]
        public IActionResult FileManager()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]
        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult GetEvents()
        {
            var events = this.Context.CalEvents.ToList();
            return new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult(new { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

HomeController - index view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var events = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/home/GetEvents",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        events.push({
                            title: v.Subject,
                            description: v.Description,
                            start: moment(v.theStart),
                            end: v.theEnd != null ? moment(v.theEnd) : null,
                            color: v.ThemeColor,
                            allDay: v.IsFullDay
                        });
                     
                    })

                    GenerateCalender(events);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            })

            function GenerateCalender(events) {
                console.log(events);
                $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calender').fullCalendar({

                    contentHeight: "auto",
                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                    timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                    },
                    eventLimit: true,
                    eventColor: '#FF0000',
                    events: events,
                    eventClick: function (CalEvents, jsEvent, view) {
                        $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(CalEvents.title);
                        var $description = $('<div/>');
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start:</b>' + CalEvents.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        if (CalEvents.end != null) {
                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + CalEvents.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        }
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + CalEvents.description));
                        $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                        $('#myModal').modal();
                    }
                   
                })
            }
        })
    </script>
}

<div id="calender"></div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle"></span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="pDetails"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the model class `CalEvents`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ExpenseTracker.Models
{
    public class CalEvents
    {
        [Key]
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime theStart {  get; set; }
        public DateTime theEnd { get; set; }
        public string? ThemeColor { get; set; }
        public Boolean? IsFullDay { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried to debug using F12 in browser and found that the records are undefined

[After running the app and press F12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCfD1.png)

Comment: You can add a console.log(data) in your ajax sucess call in order to check the json that is coming from the backend\